# Crashed VirtualBox in Ubuntu after updates

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. After I insert this:`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrad` command in terminal , because I understand wrong! So I received the message below:

```
text*Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup


as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. 
This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.



text*Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

as you are asked in the error message.

You will need to do it each time you update your kernel.